# Why does my webpage have giant spaces between text lines?

Tags: html, css

When I view my document in my browser, there are blank lines in between each line of text, which makes it look like it's double spaced. I want each line of text to be directly underneath the one before it, and not have the double spaced look. I defined the CSS styles to do what I want, but I feel like the problem is probably somewhere within there. The CSS sheet is external and imported.

```css
h5 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
h6 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftHeader">
  <h5>First line of text</h5>
  <h6>Second line of text</h6>
  <h6>last line of text</h6>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably some margin / padding defaults kicking in.

```css
h5 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
h5,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftHeader">
  <h5>First line of text</h5>
  <h6>Second line of text</h6>
  <h6>last line of text</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it! Didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the default *user agent (web browser)* styling.

Heading elements, among other elements, will have default margin and padding applied to them by the user agent. It's up to the developer to reset/normalize/modify these values.

You can remedy this by changing the top/bottom margin.

```css
.m0 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<hr>
<h2 class="m0">Heading 2</h2>
<h3 class="m0">Heading 3</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that h5 and h6 tags have standard margins at the top and bottom. Try adding this to the css

```
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
h5 {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
h6 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftHeader">
  <h5>First line of text</h5>
  <h6>Second line of text</h6>
  <h6>last line of text</h6>
</div>
```